# .htaccess - remove query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently visitors see my website in this way: example.com/index.php?s=anyword+to+search

I would like to change to example.com/anyword+to+search

My current .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/artist/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ artist/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

<IfModule mod_php5.c>  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>    

# the following is for rewritting under FastCGI
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Why are you routing everything to `/artist/` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule to redirect query string to short url :

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#http to https   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Query string to short url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/index\.php\?s=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,B,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, but where should I add it? I tried it adding right after the SSL redirection, but didn't work.

Comment: Try removing the `mod_php5` blocks and placing that line instead.

Comment: I think your `artist` rules are interfering as well. Try removing them also.